# Locating an element with dynamic ID using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I need to find an element by ID "start-ads", but the numbers at the end change every time. Is it possible to search for an element not by the whole ID, but only by its part?

```
Full element id: <div id="start-ads-202308">
```

Answer (score 1):

To identify the following element:

```
<div id="start-ads-202308">
```

considering the static part of the value of *`id`* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='start-ads-']")
  ```

  where ^ denotes starts-with
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'start-ads-')]")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find_element_by_css_selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) and use a CSS selector that matches using a prefix

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id^='start-ads-']")
```